# Run X number of Task<T> at any given time while keeping UI responsive

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a C# WinForms (.NET 4.5.2) app utilizing the TPL. The tool has a synchronous function which is passed over to a task factory `X` amount of times (with different input parameters), where `X` is a number declared by the user before commencing the process. The tasks are started and stored in a `List<Task>`.

Assuming the user entered `5`, we have this in an `async` button click handler:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    var progress = Progress(); // returns a new IProgress<T>
    var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => MyFunction(progress), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    TaskList.Add(task);
}
```

Each `progress` instance updates the UI.

Now, as soon as a task is finished, I want to fire up a new one. Essentially, the process should run indefinitely, having `X` tasks running at any given time, unless the user cancels via the UI (I'll use cancellation tokens for this). I try to achieve this using the following:

```
while (TaskList.Count > 0)
{
    var completed = await Task.WhenAny(TaskList.ToArray());                                  

    if (completed.Exception == null)
    {
        // report success
    }
    else
    {
        // flatten AggregateException, print out, etc
    }
    // update some labels/textboxes in the UI, and then:
    TaskList.Remove(completed);
    var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => MyFunction(progress), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    TaskList.Add(task);
}
```

This is bogging down the UI. Is there a better way of achieving this functionality, while keeping the UI responsive?

A suggestion was made in the comments to use TPL Dataflow but due to time constraints and specs, alternative solutions are welcome

**Update**

I'm not sure whether the progress reporting might be the problem? Here's what it looks like:

```
private IProgress<string> Progress()
{
    return new Progress<string>(msg =>
    {
        txtMsg.AppendText(msg);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for you not to use specialised tools for this task? Your scenario is exactly what TPL Dataflow is designed for.

Comment: Yes, I second Kirill - TPL Dataflow sounds a good match for this.

Comment: Time constraints, project spec, and not being aware of Dataflow (will have a read and suggest it anyhow, thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, as soon as a task is finished, I want to fire up a new one. Essentially, the process should run indefinitely, having X tasks running at any given time

It sounds to me like you want an infinite loop *inside* your task:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
  var progress = Progress(); // returns a new IProgress<T>
  var task = RunIndefinitelyAsync(progress);
  TaskList.Add(task);
}

private async Task RunIndefinitelyAsync(IProgress<T> progress)
{
  while (true)
  {
    try
    {
      await Task.Run(() => MyFunction(progress));
      // handle success
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // handle exceptions
    }
    // update some labels/textboxes in the UI
  }
}
```

However, I suspect that the "bogging down the UI" is probably in the `// handle success` and/or `// handle exceptions` code. If my suspicion is correct, then push as much of the logic into the `Task.Run` as possible.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my `// handle success/exceptions` snippet, nothing fancy. So `RunIndefinitelyAsync` will `await` each `Task.Run` call, and when done, move to the next iteration of the `while` loop, essentially achieving the same effect? How can these be cancelled then? Would it be better to replace `while(true)` with `while(SomeFlag)`? What's the `Exception` you're catching in your snippet? I have no try/catch blocks in my function being called by the tasks, I just inspect the `AggregateException` in the `.Exception` property of each task, after `Task.WaitAny`. What's more appropriate?

Comment: You can cancel these by using the standard `CancellationTokenSource`/`CancellationToken` approach, with `MyFunction` observing the `CancellationToken`. Don't use `while(SomeFlag)` to emulate cancellation - it's better to use `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in the loop body. Your code is logically doing a try/catch by examining the exceptions; the `async` code just makes the logical try/catch into a *true* try/catch, which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you simply need a parallel execution with the defined degree of parallelization. There is a lot of ways to implement what you want. I suggest to use blocking collection and parallel class instead of tasks.

So when user clicks button, you need to create a new blocking collection which will be your data source:

```
BlockingCollection<IProgress> queue = new BlockingCollection<IProgress>();
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Now you need a runner that will execute your in parallel:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    Parallel.For(0, X, i =>
    {
        foreach (IProgress p in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(source.Token))
        {
            MyFunction(p);
        }
    }), source.Token);
```

Or you can choose more correct way with partitioner. So you'll need a partitioner class:

```
private class BlockingPartitioner<T> : Partitioner<T>
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _Collection;
    private readonly CancellationToken _Token;

    public BlockingPartitioner(BlockingCollection<T> collection, CancellationToken token)
    {
        _Collection = collection;
        _Token = token;
    }

    public override IList<IEnumerator<T>> GetPartitions(int partitionCount)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<T> GetDynamicPartitions()
    {
        return _Collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(_Token);
    }

    public override bool SupportsDynamicPartitions
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

And runner will looks like this:

```
ParallelOptions Options = new ParallelOptions();
Options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = X;

Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => Parallel.ForEach(
        new BlockingPartitioner<IProgress>(queue, source.Token),
        Options,
        p => MyFunction(p)));
```

So all you need right now is to fill `queue` with necessary data. You can do it whenever you want.

And final touch, when the user cancels operation, you have two options:

- first you can break execution with [`source.Cancel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955(v=vs.110).aspx) call,
- or you can gracefully stop execution by marking collection complete ([`queue.CompleteAdding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086(v=vs.110).aspx)), in that case runner will execute all already queued data and finish.

Of course you need additional code to handle exceptions, progress, state and so on. But main idea is here.

Comment: Start New is dangerous and should not be used in this case

Comment: @arbiter, thanks. I have no comment for the solution at the moment as it's utilizing stuff I'm not experienced with. I'll mess around with your solution in the weekend and come back with questions.